# Facebook Login Button - how does it work?

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I've been reading this [Facebook Dev guide on Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

And i'm wondering how exactly does the xfbml based login button works to the point where a cookie with the user's access_token is planted in the context of your web application's domain.

I followed the above tutorial but It's quite different than the way the facebook login's button (the one which opens a popup window) works.

Is there a source which explains what's going on behind the scenes? I'm really interested in implementing something similiar.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a popup as well (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream), I believe you include display=popup and it'll popup.  Once the user is "authed", facebook then returns to the value in the redirect_uri with the access_token.  Now with this access token you can make calls on the user's behalf to the graph, by appending "access_token=" to the url.

Comment: Technically speaking, when I click the facebook login button, JavaScript opens up a new window with the Facebook URL which contains the APP_ID, REDIRECT_URI and other related parameters.
As I understand, after the user enters it's credentials, facebook redirects him back to the "REDIRECT_URI" while adding the access token as a parameter, but how does the popup know that once this is happening - close itself and reload the parent window?

Answer (score 0):

from child window you can access parent DOM

```
window.opener
```

parent script

```
function openWin()
{
    myWindow=window.open('http://apps.streetdeal.sg/buddhi/b.html','','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.focus();
}

function parent_function()
{
    alert('a');
}
```

child script

```
function child_function()
{
    window.opener.parent_function();
}
```